# Printing Collection of Usercontrols inside my flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, flowlayoutpanel

I have a collection of usercontrol inside my flowlayout panel, and I want to print usercontrols using printdocument per page. Is there any other way to solve my problems ?

I tried this code inside my printpage method -

```cs
    for (int i = numberOfItemsPrintedSoFar; i < chequeContainer.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        numberOfItemsPerPage++;
        if (numberOfItemsPerPage <= 3)
        {
            numberOfItemsPrintedSoFar++;

            if (numberOfItemsPrintedSoFar <= chequeContainer.Controls.Count)
            {
                 foreach (ClassForGettingData data in ClassForGettingData.cheque_list)
                {
                    CustomUsercontrol u = new CustomUsercontrol );
                    u.chequeInfos(data);
                    u.PrintToGraphics(e.Graphics, new Point(0, yPos));
                    yPos += 450;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.HasMorePages = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            numberOfItemsPerPage = 0;
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
numberOfItemsPerPage = 0;
numberOfItemsPrintedSoFar = 0;
```

```cs
internal void PrintToGraphics(Graphics graphics ,Point point)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
    this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));

    graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Display;
    graphics.DrawImage(bitmap ,point);
}
```

But the problem with this code is it printed all controls in one page of document only.

Comment: And you want what, 4 controls per page only?

Comment: Yes. I want to limit controls per page.  do u have other way to limit controls per page? i tried to put my yPos outside my foreach loop and it achieve to display the number of controls i want to display, but it only display the same usercontrol. I have different dynamic usercontrol.